# button not getting aligned correctly when the container is moved

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I am trying to align the button controls to the bottom right of my kendo popup window.

When I set the following styles it show fine. But the issue is when i move the popup the buttons are lost. I tried to set the position relative but it does not show at the bottom

[image]

```
.statusButtonAlign{

   position:fixed;
     bottom: 30px;
     right: 20px; 

}


.statusButtonAlign{

       position:absolute;
         bottom: 30px;
         right: 20px; 

    }
```

form

```
<div class="k-popup-edit-form k-window-content k-content "  >
    <div class="k-edit-form-container" >
      @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.CountryCode, new { data_bind = "value: CountryCode" })
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RequestID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } })
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProjectName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ProjectName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } })
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RequestStatus)
            </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
                @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(model => model.RequestStatusCode)

        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
        .DataTextField("Status")
        .Placeholder("Select...")
        .DataValueField("RequestStatusCode")
        .AutoBind(false)
        .Filter("contains")

        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource

        .Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetRequestStatus", "Request").Data("GetCountryCodeFilter").Type(HttpVerbs.Post);

        }).ServerFiltering(true)


           )
                )
            </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WorkLogDetails)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.WorkLogDetails, new { htmlAttributes = new { cols = "100" } })
        </div>

        <div class="statusButtonAlign">
            <button type="submit" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-primary k-grid-update">Update</button>
            <button id="btnClose" type="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-cancel">Cancel</button>

        </div>

        <div id="statusMessage">


        </div> 

        </div>
```